# Fluentd add new tag using value from another tag in same record

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I'm using a fluentd and I've a requirement to add a new tag inside current record. The value for this tag is present in another value in same record.

Example:

```
Sample record:
{"xff":null,"host":"0.0.0.1","method":"GET","referer":null,"url_path":"/abcd/attr1=value1&attr2=value2&noOfUsers=123456789&e="}
Expected output is:
{"xff":null,"host":"0.0.0.1","method":"GET","referer":null,"url_path":"/abcd/attr1=value1&attr2=value2&test=123456789&e=","noOfUsers":"123456789"}
```

As you see, I will be fetching the value for new tag "noOfUsers" from "url_path" value.

I searched some information and got the details, that i should use ruby script for this.

May I know what is the correct solution and what ruby script i should use to achieve this?

```
<filter *.test>
  type record_transformer
   <record>
        ?????
   </record>
   enable_ruby true
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
require 'cgi'

sample_record = {"xff":nil,"host":"0.0.0.1","method":"GET","referer":nil,"url_path":"/abcd/attr1=value1&attr2=value2&noOfUsers=123456789&e="}
new_noOfUsers = CGI::parse(sample_record[:url_path])["noOfUsers"].first
expected_record = sample_record.merge({ "noOfUsers": new_noOfUsers })
expected_record[:url_path].sub!("noOfUsers", "test")
expected_record
```

Comment: I want to do it using Ruby.